# Simple Confluent Kafka .net client fails to connect to simple build of AK Kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, librdkafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

Any hints on how to get a simple .Net Kafka client to connect to a broker?

I [built Apache Kafka](https://manasvigupta.github.io/getting-started-with-contributing-to-apache-kafka-part1-build-and-run-kafka-from-source-code/) from the [3.4.0 download](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) and followed the [quick start](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) successfully (topic created, events produced, events consumed).

Using [Confluent.Kafka v2.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Confluent.Kafka/)  I tried to read the topic metadata with:

```
var adminConfig = new AdminClientConfig();
adminConfig.BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
adminConfig.Debug = "all";

using var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(adminConfig).Build();
var metadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var topicsMetadata = metadata.Topics;
var topicNames = metadata.Topics.Select(a => a.Topic).ToList();

Console.WriteLine($"Topics: {string.Join(',', topicNames)}");
```

The `var metadata = ...` line throws Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException 'Local: Broker transport failure'

The logging in the terminal shows the following which keeps looping:

```
- xxx: Received CONNECT op
- xxx: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
- xxx: Broadcasting state change
- xxx: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
- xxx: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
- xxx: Broadcasting state change
- xxx: Connecting to ipv6#[::1]:9092 (plaintext) with socket 1308
- xxx: Connected to ipv6#[::1]:9092
- xxx: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#12)
- xxx: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
- xxx: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
- xxx: Broadcasting state change
- xxx: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Sent ApiVersionRequest (v3, 52 bytes @ 0, CorrId 12)
- xxx: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
- xxx: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
- xxx: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
- xxx: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
- xxx: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
- xxx: Cluster connection already in progress: no cluster connection
- xxx: Timed out ApiVersionRequest in flight (after 10115ms, timeout #0)
- xxx: ApiVersionRequest failed: Local: Timed out: probably due to broker version < 0.10 (see api.version.request configuration) (after 10116ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY) (_TRANSPORT): identical to last error: error log suppressed
- xxx: Updated enabled protocol features -ApiVersion to
- xxx: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> DOWN
- xxx: Broadcasting state change
- xxx: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
- xxx: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
- xxx: Updating 0 buffers on connection reset
- xxx: Timed out 1 in-flight, 0 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
- xxx: Broker changed state DOWN -> INIT
- xxx: Broadcasting state change
- xxx: Selected for cluster connection: no cluster connection (broker has 11 connection attempt(s))
```

Comment: Forking Kafka is completely unnecessary. Just download it from https://kafka.apache.org or use Docker

Comment: In any case, your error is saying that your broker isn't started successfully. Were you able to follow all of the quickstart steps? Such as creating a new topic from the CLI? And producing data to it?

Comment: Yes - all the quick start steps worked correctly (creating a topic, producing events, consuming those events).

Comment: `probably due to broker version < 0.10`... Are you not using the latest 3.4 build? What errors do you get when you actually download a pre built version?

Comment: The broker was built from:
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/apache/kafka.git
  HEAD branch: trunk

I assume 'trunk' is the latest?

Is there a way to query for, or directly see, the broker version?

Comment: The trunk branch can be unstable, even though unit tests are required before merge. The version is in one of the Gradle files, but like I said, building is completely unnecessary. Use an actual, stable release

Comment: I downloaded the Apache Kafka 3.4.0 source from here https://kafka.apache.org/downloads , built it, and ran it -- It produces exactly the same error...

Comment: You want the binary download, not source. You don't need to install and run Gradle commands

Comment: In any case, I'm not really sure. The logs say it's connecting correctly, only the topic request is timing out. You could try adding config to increase timeout

Comment: I downloaded the 3.4.0 Scala 2.1.3 binary (kafka_2.13-3.4.0.tgz) and ran it. -- It produces exactly the same error...

I tried creating a topic through the commandline then producing events to it - same error.

Comment: The Java CLI doesn't use librdkafka like the c# client does. Try seeing if you can reproduce with kcat utility

Comment: I managed to build the kcat client and run it. It gave the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message turned out to be misleading, a connection was NOT successfully made to the broker.

From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking), I discovered that the localhost address does not always correctly map between the WSL and Windows system.

I used [akhq](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq) successfully running within WSL, from Windows as localhost (http://localhost:8080/ui/local/topic) - though the kafka broker did not work as localhost (BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092" generates the error, though BootstrapServers = "172.18.212.44:9092" succeeds).

If anyone in the Kafka community sees this - perhaps the logging could be improved to help identify the issue. Specifically, the log line "- xxx: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY" seems to indicate the connection was successful, and the query for api version is what was failing - which is not the case.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Didn't realize you were using WSL2. Feel free to file an issue in the librdkafka repo